# How to fix a function

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

[image]I search during 2 hours and and I have always the same problem always. 
I'm working in nuxt.js / vue.js and I'm trying to add an contact form in my website. I'm using actually a sendmail.js with elasticmail for submit email. 
But I have an error with the code and I don't know how to resolve this.

My code in the header

```
 { src: 'https://smtpjs.com/v3/smtp.js' }
```

in the nuxt.config.js

And my code for the contact.js

```js
methods: {
 onSubmit() {
   Email.send({
     Host: 'smtp.elasticemail.com',
     Username: 'xxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com',
     Password: 'xxxxxxxxxxxx',
     To: 'xxxxxxxx@gmail.com',
     From: 'you@isp.com',
     Subject: 'This is the subject',
     Body: 'And this is the body'
   }).then((message) => alert(message))
 }
}
```

The error is = "Email is not a function"

Comment: Where do you see this error? There's nothing in the code shown that is attempting to use `Email` as a function.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by _"the code in the header"_? What you've shown there isn't going to do anything, it's just an anonymous JS object

Comment: Phil I see it in my page and in my console.log

Phil I mean i did the import script in my header

Comment: How **exactly** did you do _"the import script in my header"_? Could you also please provide a screenshot of the console error? You can [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57718994/edit) and paste images directly into the editor

Comment: Please don't post code in screenshots (for readability and searchability). You can post a screenshot of the error in your console though.